# unable to run my docker image in my local

Tags: maven, web-services, docker

I have a maven web service project run with jetty maven plugin.

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM openjdk:8
# maven
From maven:3.3.9
ENV MAVEN_VERSION 3.3.9

COPY pom.xml /home/pusher-docker/pusher-test/pom.xml

COPY src /home/pusher-docker/pusher-test/src

WORKDIR /home/pusher-docker/pusher-test 

RUN mvn package

CMD ["java","-cp","target/pusher-test.jar","mvn jetty:run"]
```

I am starting docker container with

`sudo docker run docker-pusher-test`

but I am getting the following error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in pusher-test.war
```

How I can successfully start the container?

Comment: Why you use two `FROM` in a row?

Comment: Hi Charles, its in different line

Comment: It seems that the issue happens to your application, not others. So you can have a check with your application. The error shows there something missed in your pusher-test.war